# Symbolic Code for Delete

Tags: hooks

I know about using LANGUAGE_NONE instead of 'und' for an undefined language.  Is there also a symbolic variable for a 'Delete' operation?  In my hook_node_validate, I look at the value of $node->op, which is the operation.  I test it for the value of 'Delete', if the content is being deleted.

Should I be using something other than the string 'Delete'?  I looked in bootstrap.inc, but didn't find anything there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no symbolic code/constant for 'Delete', no.

The button containing that text gets set in the main [`node_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form/7) function though:

```
$form['actions']['delete'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit', 
  '#value' => t('Delete'), 
  '#weight' => 15, 
  '#submit' => array('node_form_delete_submit'),
);
```

and making the assumption that no other module is changing the `#value` of that variable by way of a form alter, you'll be safe checking the clicked button text by wrapping the same string in [`t()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7):

```
if ($node->op == t('Delete')) {
  // ...
}
```